# Firebase concurrent read/write requests limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How many concurrent read and write request can firebase support. Can it support 50k write and 50k read concurrent requests. What will be the average response time for both read and write at this load. Assume that the data size is not huge, say only 50k records are there and each request will be reading or writing single record only.

Answer (score 3):

There is a physical limit to how much data can be written to a disk in a certain time interval (you fail to mention any time interval in your question). Firebase's limits are based on the physical limits combined with logic to keep the shared service responsive for everyone. These numbers change regularly, so we don't disclose them.

Once you reach the limit, writes will be queued and processed in turn. So any peak in write throughput will be buffered. You can detect when your writes are being buffered by using a completion listener. For buffered writes you'll see an increase in the time between when you call `set()` and when the completion listener fires.

For this specific case, I'd recommend setting up a small jsbin and simply testing it. A loop that writes 50k nodes should be simple enough:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
for (var i=0; i < 50000; i++) {
    ref.child(i).set(true).then(function(ref) {
        // this is when the write has completed
    });
}
```

You'll want to add some performance measurement logic in there, probably using [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

Comment: The problem with sending 50k requests from one machine is that, there will be limitations on the machine to send concurrent requests, hence the requests will be delayed. So we dont know when the request reaches the server.

Comment: Can it be done in case the plan is a blaze plan and there is a directive need for sharding? Just a thought... I read that 1k simultaneous writes can be done in 1 second which seems a bit too low afaik... Also does the queuing happen with the REST API?